# How to screen capture DOSBox output using OBS?

Tags: screen-capture, dosbox, obs

Just downloaded OBS Studio, and would like to record a working session in DOSBox. Most of the setup worked so nicely, but I suppose that I should have expected a few problems.

Under "Sources", I have added a Window capture, which worked immediately with the timer I have. However, I then tried adding "Game Capture" to capture the DOSBox window. This does not work, and only shows a blank screen *(pictured below)*.

- "Window Capture" also has the same effect *(blank screen)*.
- "Display Capture" does have the benefit of capturing the whole display *(including the DOSBox window)*. This works after a fashion, but is clunky, and I am not planning on running DOSBox in fullscreen. For my setup, would like to simply capture the DOSBox window.

OBS works so well in capturing other programs, I must be doing something wrong somewhere.

Any advice on where I should look next?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through this rather snarky post, it seems the problem is not with OBS.

https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/dosbox-problem.58407/

In the `dosbox.conf` file, in the `[sdl]` section, I made the following change:

*Previous value (OBS not able to capture):*

```
output=surface
```

*Current value (enables capture in OBS):*

```
output=opengl
```

This worked immediatly using `DOSBox-0.74-2` and `OBS-Studio-26.0.2`

[image]